# easiest way to convert a DateTime in rails for the non-timezone'd offset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails app that has the time zone set in application.rb with:

config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'

I'd like to save a time as:

```
day, hour=25, 10
....
params[:order][:pickup_at] = DateTime.new(2015,11,day,hour,00,00)
```

and thought it would write as

```
2015-11-25 18:00:00
```

into our table which is a Postgres 9.4 instance and the pickup_at is a timestamp without time zone.

Instead it is:

```
2015-11-25 10:00:00
```

doing:

```
params[:order][:pickup_at] =DateTime.new(2015,11,25,10,00,00).in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
```

doessn't fix. It seems what I'm trying to do is very simple. Into a timestamp adjust for what we have our current timezone set as and adjust accordingly.

How would I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

DateTime has a default offset of 0, meaning it provides you a DateTime object in UTC ("non-timezone'd" as you put it) by default:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-new

If the UTC time you want to specify is `2015-11-25 18:00:00`, you should write:

```
day, hour=25, 10
....
params[:order][:pickup_at] = DateTime.new(2015,11,day,hour,00,00,'-8')
```

That last `-8` argument is the offset, which tells DateTime that your time zone is in PST.

```
DateTime.new(2015,11,day,hour,00,00,'-8').utc
```

then yields:

```
Wed, 25 Nov 2015 18:00:00 +0000
```

If you wanted to make this dynamic against your application's Time zone, you could write:

```
day, hour = 25, 10
# Take application timezone offset in seconds and convert it to hours
hour_offset = Time.zone.utc_offset / 60 / 60 
params[:order][:pickup_at] = DateTime.new(2015,11,day,hour,00,00, hour_offset.to_s).utc
```